# How to output some data to different cells of an Excel File?

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, scripting

Example:

I have a file that has following data:

```
cvrta2100 Error 404 Fixed

cvrta2111 Licensed  Needs Fixing

cvrta2123 Error 404 Fixed

cvrta2333 Licensed  Needs Fixing
```

I am using `awk` to print this output to an Excel file:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS="|"; print "Hosts|Output|Status"}; NR > 1{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9;}' input.txt > Output.xls
```

The problem is - I am only able to get the results in a single cell i.e. "`cvrta2333 Licensed  Needs Fixing`" is all printed in a single cell.

My question: Is it possible to print each word Hosts, Output and Status in a different cell i.e. `cvrta2333` (One Cell) `Licensed` (Next Cell)  `Needs Fixing` (Next Cell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For "simple" columns like this, comma separated values will open nicely in excel.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS=","; print "Hosts,Output,Status"}; NR > 1{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9;}' input.txt > Output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

If you import the file in Excel natively, you can use the "text to table" function (or whatever it's called) to break lines into columns using a space delimiter.

I don't know how Excel will react, but you can convert your file into one with tab- or comma-delimited words using **tr**,

```
$ tr \   \\t  < input > output
$ tr \   ,    < input > output
```

I'd stay away from CSV unless that was the only one that made Excel happy, because of the need to quote commas that are part of the logfile text.